# Can I make a variable name with some calculation in python

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I like to make a variable with some calculation like below

> 'apple'+str(123)='orange'

expected below

> apple123='orange'

It looks simple but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using globals()

Example:
globals()['apple'+str(123)]='orange'

print (apple123) # will print orange

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setattr` to dynamically create variables

Answer (score 0):

you can use `exec` to create dynamic variable

```
key = 123
value = "orange"
exec(("apple{}='{}'").format(key, value))
print(apple123)
# prints
orange
```

but I would suggest you to use a Dictionary.

```
a = {'apple123': 'orange', "apple_blah": "banana"}

a['apple123'] will return orange
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries